# Set the subject mail app - people app

Tags: c#, email, share, peoplepicker

I would like to share some content from my Windows 8 Metro App to the Mailto App.
I've implemented the People App, the user can select some people and when clicked on a button the selected people are displayd (name + image) and the charm bar (share) opens up. I allready set some content (body) to sent in the email.

Now what I'm looking for, can I set the subject from the mail programmatically (people choosen from the people app)?

Comment: Have you considered the documentation or an example from MSDN?

Comment: So far I haven't found any documentation/example. I can find how to implement the people app, share content and so on. But nothing how the set subject in a email (subject choosen in people app)